# EE2.10.3 Accessories page PHP errors

Tags: php-errors, addons

With a new install of EE2.10.3, and no Add-Ons installed, I'm getting two PHP errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: ucwords() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
Filename: cp/addons_accessories.php
Line Number: 422

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Illegal offset type
Filename: cp/addons_accessories.php
Line Number: 422
```

The only Accessories listed on this page are EE Info, Learning EE, News and Stats, Quick Tips; the only one installed is EE Info.

I'm guessing that the addons will still work properly, but this is still annoying to see, and I'm not sure why it's happening. I've reinstalled EE to see if it might help, but, nope. I'm not seeing any other errors.

This is local run using XAMPP, if that makes any difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Dreamweaver added a random _notes folder to the system/expressionengine/controllers/cp directory, which caused the problem. Derek at Ellis Labs lead me in the right direction to figure it out!

https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/248756/